# Should compound nouns treated as singular or plural

Tags: grammar, adjectives, singular-vs-plural, nouns, attributive-nouns

All,
Which one is correct:
"statistical techniques is " or "statistical techniques are"

I Googled "statistical techniques is" and also "statistical techniques are" to find if any of those names are being used, and I found many results. It seems that both are being used. Am I right?
Thanks

Comment: Whether you put an adjective like ***statistical*** in front of the noun ***techniques*** doesn't affect the fact that it's a ***plural*** noun. You're probably finding singular instances in contexts like *The use of statistical techniques **is** not recommended*, where the subject is singular ***use***, not plural ***techniques***. You have to look at the words *in context*.

Comment: "Statistical techniques" is not a compound noun, but a noun phrase consisting of the head (main) word "techniques" modified by the adjective "statistical". Since the head of the noun phrase is the plural noun "techniques", it follows that the verb should be the plural "are".

Comment: Please edit to tell about the context that these would be used in. I could imagine: "Statistical Techniques is my favorite class." But not "Statistical techniques is important to know."

Comment: But note, that has nothing to do with compounds. It's just that we often use plurals as singulars when discussing fields of study, like "analytics" or "mathematics" or "Goethe studies."

Comment: Voting to close as unclear until edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, compound nouns are recognised as singular or plural by the core noun (in English, the last word).

We would say "**a** statistical technique", so "statistical *techniques*" is plural.

It is fairly unusual for any other word in a compound noun to be plural - mainly because the other words besides the core noun are usually adjectives, and you can't pluralise an adjective, 'statistical' being an example of that. But some compound nouns may use adjectival nouns that can be plural, for example, "*a statistics book*".

If you are finding examples of 'techniques' being used with 'is' it must be because the wider context demands it - for example, if it is being used as part of a singular noun phrase, for example, "*a book of techniques*".

Comment: OK, but "statistical techniques" is not a compound noun, but a syntactic construction, i.e. a noun phrase.

Comment: @BillJ good, my answer has a wider application and will help anyone who searches the question title.

Comment: Based on Wikipedia, the head in the noun phrase is the second noun, and it could be plural.

Comment: @Kernel I changed the term 'head noun' for '*core* noun' in a much earlier edit to avoid confusion, so I'm not sure why you're mentioning that now. 'Head' does sound like the first noun, that's because in other languages it may be. But second, you say "second noun", which assumes there are only two in the phrase. "Ambulance driver uniforms" has three, for example. So I felt 'core noun' was clearer and it would be the last in the phrase.

Comment: I did not notice the difference between the “head" and “core" nouns. It is clear now.  After Googling both “head” and “core” nouns, I found that the phrase “head noun" is more often used in grammar tutorials than “core noun". Nevertheless, it does not mean that “head noun” is more accurate than “core noun".

Comment: @Astralbee I read the comments above, yet I think we can edit the question title to fit the question exactly, and I think that the answer will fit, too, after replacing the “compound noun” with “noun phrase”. People searching for the compound noun's meaning may land on this page and be misguided by “statical techniques” as a compound noun.  I have been confused by some stuff like that before. What do you think?